# Delete Old or Redundant Post Metadata from Wordpress

Tags: mysql, wordpress, phpmyadmin

It appears that somehow in the past, WordPress saved multiple redundant `post_meta` for post revisions which are no longer in the database.
As a result, I have a ton of `post_meta` that does nothing and is tied to posts that no longer exist.

Does anyone know how to remove this data from phpMyAdmin with a SQL query?

Answer (score 0):

You can run a mysql query like this; [WordPress › Support » SQL Query to delete orphans wp_postmeta](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/337412?replies=7), but might be easier and safer to use a plugin like [WordPress › Mass Custom Fields Manager « WordPress Plugins](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/mass-custom-fields-manager/) or [WordPress › Custom Field Taxonomies « WordPress Plugins](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-field-taxonomies/)

Answer (score 0):

"Optimize Database" is the one I use.  Setup is very quick and easy.  It runs in the background daily cleaning out post-meta orphans, things you have trashed, and useless old "revisions".

Answer (score 0):

This has been explained here in full.

[Remove Unnecessary WP Postmeta](https://codepangs.com/delete-unnecessary-post-metadata/)

All you have to do is add the following in your theme functions.php file

```html
function delete_useless_post_meta() {
   global $wpdb;
   $table = $wpdb->prefix.'postmeta';
   $wpdb->delete ($table, array('meta_key' => '_edit_last'));
   $wpdb->delete ($table, array('meta_key' => '_edit_lock'));
   $wpdb->delete ($table, array('meta_key' => '_wp_old_slug')); }
add_action('wp_logout','delete_useless_post_meta');
```